# The Most Palindromy Code to Calculate Palindromy Numbers

Tags: string, source-layout, palindrome, self-scoring

The string

```
abaaba
```

Is a palindrome, meaning it doesn't change when it's reversed.  However we can split it in half to make two palindromes

```
aba aba
```

We could also split it up this way:

```
a baab a
```

And all three of those are palindromes.

In fact there are only two ways to split the string into smaller strings such that *none* of them are palindromes:

```
abaa ba
ab aaba
```

Any other way we split this there is going to be at least one palidrome.

So we will say that this string has a **palindromy number** of 2.  More generally a string's palindromy number is the number of ways to partition it into contiguous substrings such that none are a palindrome.

Your task will be to take a string as input and determine its palindromy number.  Your answer must work correctly for inputs containing lowercase letters (`a`-`z`) along with any characters used in the source code of your program.

### Scoring

Your answer will be scored by it's own palindromy number.  With a lower score being the goal.  In the case of ties the tie breaker is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

This scoring does mean if you solve this in brainfuck you can get a lenguage answer with a primary score of 0.  So if you are a lenguage enthusiast this is just code-golf.

[Here's a program to score your code](https://tio.run/##JY4xb4QwDIX3/IonxJAIDqkrFFSp800dKUJBBEgbCAqhB1X/OzXcYMv@7PfsQS7fypjj0ONsnce7nbyzJrnbSbaMddjwR5HncOpHuUWdDcqKqPWDcg9NiEC5VRVjPbhMmzdep7UQhHkTo5SVQIpRzuDdlWVKQ96jESBFffkxtl7O58EoAm8t7cXnyusNPbYM@qw6yAxfZ7Wiyegnv7oJISESaYhjyYPBjtbYfg/YKPWUt5YBRnnM0vmFTqxYiMxOT56URk29H55DwvTgvQb/5Fu8i1sxr/7DO74M9oEtioIUgSiKp3YX4a@ey5ckqULyPP4B).

### Test cases

```
a -> 0
aba -> 0
ababa -> 0
abababa -> 0
ffffffff -> 0
xyz -> 1
abaa -> 1
abaaa -> 1
abaaaaa -> 1
ooooooops -> 1
kvxb -> 2
kayak -> 2
abaaba -> 2
abaaaba -> 2
avakava -> 2
aaaaakykaaaaa -> 2
abaaaaba -> 3
ababab -> 4
abababab -> 8
```

Comment: Why doesn't the scoring code partition homology into length 1 partitions? E.g, shouldn't xyz be x yz and xy z , therefore 2? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Is the answer that len 1 partitions are considered palindromes? Wouldn't that make xyz score 0? Or is no partition considered a partitioning?

Comment: @MVirts The scoring doesn't partition into strings of length 1 because they are always palindromes.  Any partition with a length 1 string has a palindrome partition (the same is true of length 0 partitions).  The 1 partition of xyz is indeed the trivial partition.  xyz is not a palindrome so the partition of one element contains no palindromes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 3, 755962277730462996760664 bytes

```
...‘‘‘‘ṃØJV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/c1NTSzMjI3Nzc2MDEzMjS0szczMDMzODhzubDM7zC/hsZHFr0qGlN5P9ErsQkMIaRQDoNCrgqKqtAgmAZGAmk8yGgoJgru6wiiSs7sTIxGyyZBFUDossSs4GYC6wjuzIbohNiAtwqmI1JXI8aZuBBUFcDAA)

-5 score and +tons of bytes thanks to @ovs's idea.

`...‘‘‘‘` part contains exactly 755962277730462996760660 copies of `‘` character, whose length encodes the following program in base 256:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ɠŒṖŒḂ€€§¬S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///kgqOTHu6cBiR2ND1qWgNEh5YfWhP838jg0CIgJ/J/IldiEhjDSCCdBgVcFZVVIEGwDIwE0vkQUFDMlV1WkcSVnViZmA2WTIKqAdFlidlAzAXWkV2ZDdEJMQFuFczGJK5HDTPwoIc7mw/P8AoDAA)

The main code is a minor variation of [Dude's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233917/78410) (use of alternative built-ins, and input method changed to "a single line from stdin"), so here goes an explanation for the encoding part instead:

```
...‘‘‘‘ṃØJV    Main link (niladic).
...‘‘‘‘        Increment from zero 755..whatever..660 times
       ṃØJ     Base decompress into Jelly's code page
          V    Eval as a nilad (input is handled in the code itself)
```

The 3 non-palindromic partitions of `...aaaabcde` are:

```
...aaaabcde
...aaaabc|de
...aaaab|cde
```

Comment: I think you can replace `...““““”L` with 383640471319762569300 times `‘`

Comment: @ovs No, it errors since the program is a monad taking a string, and placing a leading 0 defeats the purpose of the encoding. EDIT: It might actually save some score if I change the input method.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't include the input when I tried this. But could you make the encoded program read the input from stdin instead?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of exactly that.

Comment: You've turned Jelly into Lenguage. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score <s>14</s> 12, 9 bytes

```
ŒṖŒḂ€€§¬§
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pwGJHU2PmtYA0aHlh4D4/8Mdmx7uWHS4nevh7i2H24Hikf//Jyro2ikYcCUmIRgoTBgnDQogvIrKKhDDEKQmEcFCZsI4@RBQUAzhZpdVJIFYRlzZiZWJ2RAmSAPEIggbwSlLzAZiKAcEsiuz4YZDFUNVG0MdDGKbwBwP5llwYQ8QsIuMAA)

I thought this would be more of a baseline contender, but any modification I make to it to try to make it more palindromy only increases it instead. So, this is just the straight forward implementation.

-2 points thanks to [xigoi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98955/xigoi)

### How it works

```
ŒṖŒḂ€€§¬§ - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
ŒṖ        - Get all partitions of S
     €    - Over each partition:
    €     -   Over each substring in the partition:
  ŒḂ      -     Is the substring a palindrome?
      §   - Get the sum of each (counting how many substrings are palindromic)
       ¬  - Logical not. Map zeros to one, everything else to zero
        § - Sum, counting the zeros
```

Comment: -2 by replacing `ċ0` with `¬§`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pwGJHU2PmtYA0aHlh4D4/8Mdmx7uWHS4nevh7i2H24Hikf//Jyro2ikYcCUmIRgoTBgnDQogvIrKKhDDEKQmEcFCZsI4@RBQUAzhZpdVJIFYRlzZiZWJ2RAmSAPEIggbwSlLzAZiKAcEsiuz4YZDFUNVG0MdDGKbwBwP5llwYQ8QsIuMAA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score 18 (9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
.œεεÂÊ]PO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jkc1vPbT3cdLgrNsD////EpEQgAgA) or [verify all test cases, including itself](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/0X@/o5HNbz2093HS4KzbA/7/SoW0X9hxa6Vl8dGFZpb2SwqO2SQpK9pWH1umF6fjFZx7aZv8/WilRSUdBKTEJRiExIMw0KACxKyqroLIwVUgMCDMfAgqKQZzssookMJ1YmZgNU5iE0AJlliVmAzGYCQLZldlw4yAmIzsKyXlJSrEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ      # Get all partitions of the (implicit) input-string
  ε     # Map over each partition:
   ε    #  Map over each part in this partition:
        #   Check that it's NOT a palindrome by:
    Â   #    Bifurcating it (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy)
     Ê  #    And check that this reversed copy is not equal to the original string
  ]     # Close both nested maps
   P    # Check for each partition whether no part was a palindrome
    O   # Sum to get the amount of truthy values
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

I don't think this score nor byte-count can be improved, but I'd like to be proven wrong. Increasing the program size overall increases the score, otherwise `Ê]PO` to `Q]O_O` would have been a decent change with the palindrome `O_O` (this scores 22 at 10 bytes btw).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 25 bytes, score 46368

```
LṄvṖ⁽JḭUƛvɾ:?f$•;'ƛḂ≠;A;L
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=L%E1%B9%84v%E1%B9%96%E2%81%BDJ%E1%B8%ADU%C6%9Bv%C9%BE%3A%3Ff%24%E2%80%A2%3B%27%C6%9B%E1%B8%82%E2%89%A0%3BA%3BL&inputs=abaaba&header=&footer=)

-3 thanks to Aaron Miller.

A big mess. Part of the code [shamelessly stolen from Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233186/100664).

```
L                         # Length
 ṄvṖ                      # All permutations of partitions
    ⁽Jḭ                   # Flatten by 1 level
       U                  # Uniquify
        ƛ       ;         # Foreach
         vɾ:?f$•          # Mold input to those pieces (see above link)
                 '     ;L # Number of values where
                  ƛḂ≠;A   # All aren't palindromes.
```

Comment: [25 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=L%E1%B9%84v%E1%B9%96%E2%81%BDJ%E1%B8%ADU%C6%9Bv%C9%BE%3A%3Ff%24%E2%80%A2%3B'%C6%9B%E1%B8%82%E2%89%A0%3BA%3BL&inputs=abaaba&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), score 21 (9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax))

```
Æ₧ⁿ+Ü█>la
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=929efc2b9adb3e6c61&i=%C3%86%E2%82%A7%E2%81%BF%2B%C3%9C%E2%96%88%3Ela%0A%3A%21%7B%7Bcr%3Df%21f%25%0Aa%0Aaba%0Aababa%0Aabababa%0Affffffff%0Axyz%0Aabaa%0Aabaaa%0Aabaaaaa%0Aooooooops%0Akvxb%0Akayak%0Aabaaba%0Aabaaaba%0Aavakava%0Aaaaaakykaaaaa%0Aabaaaaba%0Aababab%0Aabababab%0A&m=2)

the packed representation scores lesser, as shown in the tests.

Despite the existence of `f!f` and `{{` in the unpacked version, the number of characters simply doubles the score.